# Text in button not staying on one line

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner at CSS and HTML and can't figure this out. I've tried using `max-height`, `line height` and `line-clamp` Nothing works.

HTML code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet home.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" style="height: 500px">
        <p>Welcome to the FIFA tournament creator</p>
        <a href="#" class="blue btn">Get Started</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

div
{
}
#div1
{
    background-image: url(../Images/div1.png);
    min-height: 440px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: molengo, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.btn {
    background: #CCC;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0 3em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: linear-gradient(#11A1D6,#0E86B2);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #0E86B2;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: left;   
}
.blue.btn {
    background: linear-gradient(#11A1D6,#0E86B2);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #0E86B2; 
}
.btn:hover { 
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), 
    inset 0 1.5em 1em rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.btn:active { 
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), 
    inset 0 1.5em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
}
```

Comment: remove the **width**! http://jsfiddle.net/He9QJ/

Comment: Remove the **height!** also, you added too much styles to the link. Start removing styles that you don't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are getting the majority of your width from padding. Padding is exactly what it sounds like - internal empty space that is used to frame the element.

*This is not to be confused with **margin** which is empty space around the element*.

To fix your problem, you need to get usable width, as defined by the width element. This is currently set to 50px, which is not big enough for your text. In fact, the only reason you even see the entire word "started" is because you don't have the overflow property set.

---

Simply remove the `width:50px` from your button or set it to `auto` and it will work. I also changed your button's padding to maintain the original size. You can also remove the height value and replace it with vertical padding to center your text:

> padding: 10px 1em;
>   <s>height: 50px;</s>
>   <s>width: 50px</s>;

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhF2e/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width: 50px` to make it works. Your button's width is to short.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/MgvPB/

Comment: With a `padding-top: 15px` within `.btn` will make the text look vertically center as well and `div p {color: #000}` will make the text black